# How to add a route in with blade into parameters of a component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I guess it's an easy one, but I spent 30 minutes trying to figure out how to write this correctly :

```
@component('components.button', [
    'color' => 'danger',
    'formaction' => 'formaction="'{{ route('profiles.destroy', $user->id) }}'"'
    ])
@lang('Supprimer')
```

My button component :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn @isset($color){{ ' btn-' . $color }}@else btn-primary @endisset
float-right " @isset($formaction){{ $formaction }}>
{{ $slot }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade directives starting with an `@` contain PHP code, which means your string concatenation and blade variable replacement doesn't work. It is actually way simpler:

```
@component('components.button', [
    'color' => 'danger',
    'formaction' => route('profiles.update', $user->id)
])
@endcomponent
@lang('Supprimer')
```

```
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn @isset($color){{ ' btn-' . $color }}@else btn-primary @endisset
float-right " 
        @isset($formaction)formaction="{{ $formaction }}"@endisset>
   {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

You can make the component code a little nicer when you perform calculations before:

```
@php($btnColorClass = isset($color) ? 'btn-'.$color : 'btn-primary')
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn {{ $btnColorClass }} float-right"
        @isset($formaction)formaction="{{ $formaction }}"@endisset>
   {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it on button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn @if(isset($color)) {{ ' btn-'.$color }} @else {{ 'btn-primary' }} @endif float-right "
@if(isset($formaction)) action="{{ $formaction }}" @endif>
            {{ $slot }}
    </button>
```